# ipython notebook and psycopg2 don't work together

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, psycopg2, postgresql-9.3

I am new with using mac os, maybe thats why i got such troubles.

So firstly I found out problem with running ipython notebook and successfully solved it with this two commands in shell (thx to stackoverflow):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Now only after this two commands I can run ipython notebook.

Then I tried to download psycopg2 and after 6 hours I found out the solution of problem with installing this package (again thx to stackoverflow):

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/lib
```

But now I got new problem:
**ipython notebook doesn't run in browser after `DYL_LYBRARY_PATH`, so I can't use both this solutions at the same time.**

Guys, could you please recommend me some cure, I don't know how to manage with this ....:(

Thanks!

P.S. by the way in the terminal psycopg2 works correctly, so the problem is to make it work in the browser

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd284aa2cf56> in <module>()
----> 1 import psycopg2

/Users/KB/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in <module>()
     48 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
     49 
---> 50 from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
     51 
     52 from psycopg2._psycopg import Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/KB/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/KB/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```